# Can't change font

Tags: fonts

I have emacs25 build from source (25.0.95).

And the only configure in my init.el is:

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:family "Ubuntu Mono" :foundry "DAMA" :slant normal :weight normal :height 241 :width normal)))))
```

But when I open `emacs`, the font is not changed, if I eval that code manually after `emacs` is opened, the font is changed.

I also tried this:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda ()
                 (if (display-graphic-p)
                 (custom-set-faces
                  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
                  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
                  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
                  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
                  '(default ((t (:family "Ubuntu Mono" :foundry "DAMA" :slant normal :weight normal :height 241 :width normal))))))))
```

The font is still not changed.

Tried solution from @ManuelUberti, still doesn't work for me. And I also notice when I open `emacs`, screen has a quick flash which looks like the font is changed (bigger), but some how it seems changed back to default.

Comment: I set my default font using one of the techniques mentioned in the above linked thread: Setting `emacs*font: Monoid` in `~/.Xdefaults` followed by `xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults` in the terminal. To keep things clean, if you use this `.Xdefault` or `.Xresources` method, remove **all** default font customizations from your emacs config.

Comment: How did you build Emacs? The possible ways to configure fonts depend on which GUI framework you choose when you run `./configure`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```el
(when (member "DejaVu Sans Mono" (font-family-list))
  (set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "DejaVu Sans Mono"))
```

or

```el
(when (member "DejaVu Sans Mono" (font-family-list))
    (add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist '(font . "DejaVu Sans Mono-10"))
    (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "DejaVu Sans Mono-10")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I build Emacs from sources too, but this also works on Emacs installed using the package manager on Fedora 23:

```el
(set-face-attribute 'default nil
                    :family "Source Code Pro"
                    :height 130)
```

Answer (score 0):

I set font in my .emacs like so :- `(set-frame-font "PragmataPro 13")`